# Exporting function from DLL syntax

Tags: c++, dll, syntax, export

In export.def file one can put such lines:

```
LIBRARY plug
EXPORTS
    funcName
    main=funcName
```

What is the effect of exporting function in such a way? Does it export two function names, which belong to the same function? Or does it just exports function, giving it another name?

Comment: I didn't realize def files were still used. I thought they were heavily deprecated and use of them very much discouraged.

Comment: Could you please post a link which tells about why it is deprecated? Can't find anything related in google.

Comment: Module definition files are not deprecated.  They are optional, since most things you do with them can be done with __declspec(dllexport) and linker switches.  But you can make an export alias without a dllexport (which is what this question is about), nor can you specify an ordinal (sometimes necessary for binary compatibility).  The .def file puts everything you need to know about a DLLs configuration in a single place (useful for source control).  Otherwise you have to go probing around through project files or makefiles (for linker options) and source files (for dllexports).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyx1zcd3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):

> The EXPORTS keyword can be on the same line as the first definition or
>   on a preceding line. The .def file can contain one or more EXPORTS
>   statements.
>
> The syntax for export definitions is:
>
> ```
> entryname[=internalname] [@ordinal [NONAME]] [PRIVATE] [DATA]
> ```
>
> entryname is the function or variable name that you want to export.
>   This is required. If the name you export is different from the name in
>   the DLL, specify the export's name in the DLL with internalname. For
>   example, if your DLL exports a function, func1() and you want it to be
>   used as func2(), you would specify:
>
> ```
> EXPORTS func2=func1
> ```